# how to split a textbox into multple subtextboxes for each character

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am designing a PHP form that contains some input fields as displayed in below image.

[image: Input Fields]

How can I split an input type(textbox) into single character sub-textboxes OR a textbox into multi-column textboxes for each character separately for given string.

And how to insert the data in it e.g. `|JOHN DOE|` into `|J|O|H|N| |D|O|E|` this manner

Comment: you can split your textbox value to char array.

Comment: @i3lai3la 
 
I also required layout of input box as displayed in image

Comment: Take a look at this URL : http://jsfiddle.net/w564j/ and make sure you design your own box to fit the text spacing.

Comment: @i3lai3la Nice one. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may visit this URL http://jsfiddle.net/w564j/ for sample

HTML

```
<input type="text" maxlength="9" id="text"/>
```

CSS

```
#text{
    background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4oAWWCcNNz4/Tjr3nKNyVUI/AAAAAAAAPLU/Pouua-pNsEY/s1600/sq.gif");    
    width: 195px;
    height: 18px;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
}
```

Comment: The characters don't fit too well. after a few characters they leave the box but this is a nice answer

Comment: INCREASE PADDING padding-left: 7px;

Comment: @NaveenK.Sanadhya accept the answer if it worked for you